# Cropping a photo using only JavaScript which accepts a URL as input

Tags: javascript, security, image-processing, client-side

Is there any way to crop a photo using client side JavaScript only?

When I tried searching for such a tool, the JavaScript part always uses DHTML to simply allow the user to select which area of an image to crop and then sends that information to a server side script (e.g. ASP, PHP) to actually perform the crop.

I realize that JavaScript can't create files or request them, however I think workarounds should be possible. As far is input, I want the JavaScript file to take in a URL of an image. This is simple and you can easily create an `<image>` element to display it. As far as output, I was hoping for a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) solution.

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516117/how-to-scale-an-image-in-data-uri-format-in-javascript-real-scaling-not-using/2521335#2521335) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) exist, however, when I try using them (http://jsfiddle.net/sfjsfid/skm6V/1/), I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

The reason this happens is because the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements) states that this error must be generated when you request an image from a different domain than where the page is hosted.

Is there any other way to have a pure client side JavaScript solution of cropping images which can come from a different domain?

If I try using a data uri instead of an image from a different domain (http://jsfiddle.net/VX2z2/), it works correctly. However, to be able to use a URL to an image as the input, I would need to convert it to a data URI somehow. Using a canvas won't work because of the security issues I have already discussed. Even if I find a web service which I could use, it wouldn't work either because then I would be sending an Ajax request to an external domain, which is another security risk that is blocked by the browser.

Hosting my own version of a web service or hosting server side code is not an option.

Any other ideas? Or is the only option to accept a data uri as the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break the security model, you'll need to do something other than a web application -- like a Firefox extension, for example.  This would give you additional privileges for making requests, even saving the image.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to work around the security model. You need server-side help to request data from a different domain and access it from JavaScript.